# Check string if Symmetrical and palindrome

Tags: java

I just go the Symmetrical  at [makeuseof](https://www.makeuseof.com/check-if-a-string-is-symmetrical/) and it's currently in javascript and i converted it to Java, However there's an error on the line 38 which is the array. Please check the code below, Thank you.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
    class check
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String str, rev = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string:");
        str = sc.nextLine();
        int length = str.length();
        for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            rev = rev + str.charAt(i);
        //Check if Symmetrical
        if (isSymmetrical(str)) {
            System.out.println(str +" is a symmetrical");
        } else {
            System.out.println(str +" is not a symmetrical");
        }
        //Check if palindrome
        if (str.equals(rev))
            System.out.println(str +" is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println(str +" is not a palindrome");
    }
    public static boolean isSymmetrical(String str){
        double midIndex;
        var length = str.length();

        if (length % 2 == 0) {
            midIndex = Math.floor(length/2);
        }
        else {
            midIndex = Math.floor(length/2) + 1;
        }
            var pointer1 = 0;
            var pointer2 = midIndex;
            while(pointer1 < midIndex && pointer2 < length) {
                if(str[pointer1] == str[pointer2]) {
                    pointer1 += 1;
                    pointer2 += 1;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
    }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: In Java, we cannot access the characters of a `String` with array-brackets. We would use [`String::charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) instead.

Comment: I did the if(str.charAt(pointer1) == str.charAt(pointer2)) { it worked on pointer1 however pointer2 giving me error of incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Comment: gonna try str.charAt((int)pointer2))

Comment: `pointer2` is a `double`. We can use only `int`s for `charAt(...)` (as well was array access).

Comment: @Mashwishi consider using a proper data type instead of var when declaring a variable. It'll definitely help you more in ensuring the expected data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to for sharing the [`String::charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) this is very helpful

I used charAt and convert double to int.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
    class check
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String str, rev = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string:");
        str = sc.nextLine();
        int length = str.length();

        for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            rev = rev + str.charAt(i);
        //Check if Symmetrical
        if (isSymmetrical(str)) {
            System.out.println(str +" is a symmetrical");
        } else {
            System.out.println(str +" is not a symmetrical");
        }
        //Check if palindrome
        if (str.equals(rev))
            System.out.println(str +" is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println(str +" is not a palindrome");
    }
    public static boolean isSymmetrical(String str){
        double midIndex;
        int length = str.length();
        
        if (length % 2 == 0) {
            midIndex = Math.floor(length/2);
        }
        else {
            midIndex = Math.floor(length/2) + 1;
        }
            int pointer1 = 0;
            double pointer2 = midIndex;
            while(pointer1 < midIndex && pointer2 < length) {
                if(str.charAt(pointer1) == str.charAt((int)pointer2)) {
                    pointer1 += 1;
                    pointer2 += 1;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]